# gmod dedicated server addon installation

Tags: mods, server-administration, garrys-mod

After I set up a dedicated server for Garry's Mod, I've been trying to install addons for it. I followed the directions [here](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Workshop_for_Dedicated_Servers) in an effort to to install addons from my collection [here](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=347274004)
but not all of the addons seem to be downloading, and I'm missing some addons (found when I join my own server and some are not listed). In an effort to mitigate this I've tried to manually load all the .gma files in my server's addon folder, but they do not seem to be loading. Is there any way I can force my server to include all the addons in the addon folder?

Also, to get the add on folders I've loaded them from my client's workshop addon files. Each of those were listed with names separated by underscores and with a unique ID after them. Yet on my server the addons are listed with only the unique ID, so I've copied my client addon files to the server with only the ID. However. I still do not seem to be able to load the files.

PS: to start the server I have a shortcut with target ""C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\gmod server\steamapps\common\GarrysModDS\srcds.exe" +host_workshop_collection 347274004 -authkey XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is connected to your steam collection they should download all of the addons onto the server and all of its players. For .gma files you'll need to convert them into a folder. That's what I used since most of the time my Collection worked. Try re-setting your Steam APIKey [here](http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey) and updating your startup file accordingly.